# What are the most prominent dispute resolution frameworks deployed on Ethereum

Tags: consensus, framework, tools, algorithm

Dispute Resolution may become a very important paradigm for multidimensional consensus systems such as Ethereum in the near future. In this perspective, I am going through the existing dispute resolution frameworks deployed on Ethereum such as Kleros. Are there any other promising and prominent dispute resolution systems on Ethereum ?

Answer (score 1):

There is Augur protocol which uses Universes,

https://github.com/AugurProject/augur

very complex system

Comment: Could you please elaborate how Augur protocol addresses dispute resolution in prediction markets. I could not find the details from the GitHub repo.

Comment: the whitepaper will help you